# Why is Google Chrome scrollbar width an odd number (15px) ?

Tags: google-chrome, scrollbar

It seems like a strange decision, this makes the available screen width also an odd number.

Say I have a 900px centered block on a page, and a 1600px centered background behind it.

To make the background lighter, all the pixels where the block is supposed to be are blank (from pixels 350 to 1250).

In Google chrome, a 1px white border appears on the left of the block.

Is there a reason for this ? Any way to deal with this issue ?

Comment: Can you show us your html/css? Don't understand what influence the scrollbar width would have.

Comment: Nothing else than #block{margin:0 auto;} and #wrapper{background-position-x:centered;}. If you have a 1600px monitor your document width in Chrome would be 1585px, so your background will be shifted 1px left or right.

Comment: I would suggest that rather than having your 'block' blank on the background, either fill the background in and set the background of the block on top of it. Or cut out a left and right section of your background and set them as the backgrounds of divs to the left and right of your block (anchored to the right and left respectively).
It doesn't matter what width the scrollbar is, if the user had resized the browser to be an odd number of pixels it would have broken your layout anyway.

Comment: I would like to keep it simple as it works in every other browsers (including IE7+). Of course the background has to be filled in a way so that it's ok if it's shifted (window resize as you mentioned), but still, it's not a clever decision.